# ts-node-dev (and ts-node) with ecmascript export/modules

Tags: node.js, typescript, es6-modules, ts-node

In an attempt to update typescript to a more modern standard (especially since libraries like nanoid no longer support commonjs exports), we are trying to get `ts-node-dev` library working with exporting to ecmascript modules.

The configuration is as follow:

--- package.json

```
{
  "name": "test002",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "NODE_ENV=production node ./javascript/app-ts.mjs",
    "build": "tsc && rm -rf build && rsync -avq --exclude 'build' --exclude '.gitignore' --exclude 'test' --exclude 'jest.config.js' --exclude '.idea' --exclude '__mocks__' . ./build",
    "start-test": "node src/bin/www.mjs",
    "debug": "NODE_ENV=development tsnd --respawn src/app-ts.mts"
  },
  // ..
```

--- tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    /* Visit https://aka.ms/tsconfig.json to read more about this file */

    /* Basic Options */
    "target": "es2019",                          /* Specify ECMAScript target version: 'ES3' (default), 'ES5', 'ES2015', 'ES2016', 'ES2017', 'ES2018', 'ES2019', 'ES2020', or 'ESNEXT'. */
    "module": "NodeNext",                     /* Specify module code generation: 'none', 'commonjs', 'amd', 'system', 'umd', 'es2015', 'es2020', or 'ESNext'. */
    "lib":  ["es2015","es2019","es2020"],                             /* Specify library files to be included in the compilation. */
    "sourceMap": true,                     /* Generates corresponding '.map' file. */
    "outDir": "javascript",                        /* Redirect output structure to the directory. */

    /* Strict Type-Checking Options */
    "strict": true,                           /* Enable all strict type-checking options. */

    /* Module Resolution Options */
    "esModuleInterop": true,                  /* Enables emit interoperability between CommonJS and ES Modules via creation of namespace objects for all imports. Implies 'allowSyntheticDefaultImports'. */


    /* Advanced Options */
    "skipLibCheck": true,                     /* Skip type checking of declaration files. */
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true  /* Disallow inconsistently-cased references to the same file. */


  },
  "exclude": [
    ".idea",
    "build",
    "node_modules",
    "typings/globals",
    "typings/modules",
    "test"
  ],
  "include": [
    "src/**/*"
  ],
  "files": [
    "src/global.d.ts",
    "src/types.d.ts"
  ]
}
```

If the compilation happens through `tsc` (Or through `npm run build` to copy all files in place as well) the project runs well.

However running through `npm run debug` gives this error:

```
19:06:16 ts-node-dev ver. 2.0.0 (using ts-node ver. 10.9.1, typescript ver. 5.1.6)
/home/paul/Documents/webasupport/spiderwebplugins/bff2/src/app-ts.mts:6
import * as http from "http";
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
    at internalCompileFunction (node:internal/vm:73:18)
    at wrapSafe (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1153:20)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1197:27)
    at Module._compile (/home/paul/Documents/webasupport/spiderwebplugins/bff2/node_modules/source-map-support/source-map-support.js:568:25)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1287:10)
    at require.extensions..jsx.require.extensions..js (/tmp/ts-node-dev-hook-34321391877988616.js:114:20)
    at Object.nodeDevHook [as .js] (/home/paul/Documents/webasupport/spiderwebplugins/bff2/node_modules/ts-node-dev/lib/hook.js:63:13)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1091:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:938:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1115:19)
```

I've also tried manual:

```
tsnd --respawn src/app-ts.mts
```

Or a more fundamental way:

```
ts-node src/app-ts.mts
```

The latter gives the erro:

```
TypeError [ERR_UNKNOWN_FILE_EXTENSION]: Unknown file extension ".mts" for /home/paul/Documents/webasupport/spiderwebplugins/bff2/src/app-ts.mts
    at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:405:5)
    at Object.getFileProtocolModuleFormat [as file:] (node:internal/modules/esm/get_format:99:9)
    at defaultGetFormat (node:internal/modules/esm/get_format:142:36)
    at defaultLoad (node:internal/modules/esm/load:91:20)
    at DefaultModuleLoader.load (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:263:26)
    at DefaultModuleLoader.moduleProvider (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:179:22)
    at new ModuleJob (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:63:26)
    at DefaultModuleLoader.#createModuleJob (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:203:17)
    at DefaultModuleLoader.getJobFromResolveResult (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:156:34)
    at DefaultModuleLoader.getModuleJob (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:141:17) {
  code: 'ERR_UNKNOWN_FILE_EXTENSION'
}
```

Which seems to indicate ts-node is not running as modules. (all google results tell me to remove `"type": "module"` from package.json, but the point is to make that work.

A final option I saw is to add `--esm` option to ts-node. But adding that seems to have the exact same error.

How can I make `ts-node` and correspondingly `ts-node-dev` work with esm modules, or is there another way to get hot-reloading working in typescript?

Answer (score 0):

I'm also having trouble with ts-node-dev with ESM. To make it work I am using nodemon along with ts-node. Here my config:

```
//tsconfig.json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ESNext",
    "module": "NodeNext",
    "moduleResolution": "NodeNext",
    "outDir": "dist",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "strict": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true
  },
  "ts-node": {
    "esm": true
  },
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "./*.ts", "__test__"]
}

//package.json
{
  ...
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "tsc",
    "test": "node --experimental-vm-modules node_modules/.bin/jest",
    "dev": "nodemon src/index.ts",
    "start": "node dist/index.js"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/jest": "^29.5.3",
    "@types/node": "^20.4.8",
    "jest": "^29.6.2",
    "nodemon": "^3.0.1",
    "ts-jest": "^29.1.1",
    "ts-node": "^10.9.1",
    "typescript": "^5.1.6"
  }
  ...
}
```

Check this [issue](https://github.com/wclr/ts-node-dev/issues/314) for more details.
Also, I've created this [tutorial](https://dev.to/mangadev/set-up-hot-reload-for-typescript-esm-projects-42en) with more details.